# Why can't I see a particular directory on a network share?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares

I have a windows 7 machine and a windows XP laptop.

The XP machine has C drive shared, and 
the checkbox that says "Allow network users to change my files" is checked.

[image]

From the Win7 machine I can do a `net use x: \\10.0.0.11\c` and get a drive mapped. 
I can also do this from Win7 Explorer.  I see the drive.

When I traverse the directory tree though, my home "My Documents" directory is unviewable.  In Explorer I get "Access Denied".

Why?  How can I fix this so I get read/write access?

The "My Documents" folder does not have "make this folder private" checked in Explorer.

I find these network sharing things so frustrating.

Seems to me it's not a firewall issue, because I can map the drive.

Comment: The `My Documents` folder has user-specific permissions. Make sure XP and Windows 7 have the same user and password combination and see if that works.

Comment: I cannot do that.  these are different machines, they are not in the same domain.  they each have their own machine-specific domain I guess. When I connect to the XP machine, I login with the XP-local machine-domain and user id and password.   I believe when I connect, I am authenticating as the user that is known to XP.  I can also connect via Remote Desktop, using the same authentication.  So I'm sure the authentication part is working.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the share locally on XP? Type in the same `\\10.0.0.11\c` on the XP box and see if you can see that folder.